# Pull data from a repeat and use for calculations in Survey123

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123, operations-dashboard, dashboard, arcgis-survey123-connect

Is it possible to have repeats, pull data from those repeats, and then use that pulled data to make hidden calculations like averages in Survey123? I am building a survey and wanted to avoid using repeats to avoid having a related table(s) created because I want to build a dashboard out of the data and related tables makes it much more complicated. However, I don't think I'll be able to avoid using repeats due to the type of data I am collecting. Therefore, I was hoping that using repeats and taking the data from those repeats for calculation, like averages, would then ensure that all of the data I want to use for the dashboard is stored in the layer, and can avoid having to deal with the related tables much within Dashboards. In case it is important, the type of data I am collecting is regarding fish species and catch information: user chooses the fish species they caught and then repeats allow the user to submit individual catch lengths for each fish caught within that species, along with whether each fish was either kept or released, which is why I think repeats are unavoidable; the user can submit *'infinite'* individual catch lengths, and whether that individual fish was kept or released, per each species caught. We want the individual data for each individual for other research purposes, but for the sake of the Dashboard, average catch lengths, for example, would be fine.

Comment: Have you looked into the aggregate functions that can be used with repeats?  See https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/xlsformrepeats.htm (search on the page for "aggregate") and https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-repeats/ba-p/898041 (again, search for "aggregate").  Using the `count()` and `sum()` functions and dividing the sum by the count should produce the average.  (Be sure to use the count function only on a required field, as it won't count empty values.)

Comment: @SonofaBeach I will give that a shot, thank you!!

Comment: If it works, don't forget to come back and write up an answer (and then mark the answer as correct).

Comment: @SonofaBeach so I was able to get it with a few different simple aggregate functions, so thank you for that! However it did work when trying it out through Survey123 Connect, but for some reason the aggregates aren't working when published to AGOL, and I'm not really sure what that is about.